# Como puedo alinear los items de un JComboBox a la derecha?

Tags: java, java-swing, combobox

Veo que no existe el método `setHorizontalAlignment()` para un `JComboBox` y tampoco encuentro el método para esto en el `CellRenderer`. Lo que quiero es que cada item automáticamente aparezca alineado a la derecha del `JComboBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como en la lista desplegable cada valor esta 'renderizado' como un `JLabel` entonces para alinear el texto debería bastar con algo como:

`((JLabel)miComboBox.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);`